# Variable not passing trough (maybe end of scope)

Tags: c++, scope, sfml

So I am trying to assign a variable trough a function. The code in the function would normally exist in the constructor but because I dont want to have to write it in the constructor for all the classes that inherite the same parent I made a function.

But the function doesnt seem to work properly or assign the vallue properly.

This is the code in the constructor:

```
sf::Texture holdTexture;
sf::Sprite holdSprite;

Wolf::Wolf(float speed, Player& p) :
    Monster(speed, p)
{   
    holdTexture.loadFromFile("Assets\\Wolf.png");
    sprite.setTexture(holdTexture);
    sprite.setOrigin(24,22);
}
```

The sprite value is declared in a parent-parent-parent called Entity.h

```
class Entity {
public:
    Entity();
    sf::Sprite sprite;
public:
    sf::Vector2f getEntityCoords();
protected:
    void loadSprite(const std::string &filename);
};
```

Which has the function:

```
void Entity::loadSprite(const std::string &filename) {
    sf::Texture holdTexture;
    holdTexture.loadFromFile(filename);
    sprite.setTexture(holdTexture);
}
```

So now my constructor looks like:

```
Wolf::Wolf(float speed, Player& p) :
    Monster(speed, p)
{   
    loadSprite("Assets\\Wolf.png");
}
```

Wolf is derived from Monster. Monster is derived from Entity. And the call to loadSprite works.

But now the sprite just turns into a white box. As the title says, it may be an end of scope issue but I am not experienced enough with c++ to know for sure. Looking around hasnt gotten me an answer too. I hope this is not a stupid question. If you need to see more code please ask, it would be great if someone could help :)

Comment: Monster is derived from Entity? Its not clear. You *really* must use a naming convention for member variables (m_sprite, sprite_ ,...)

Comment: does entity.loadSprite get called? (break in debugger or trace statement)

Comment: `sprite = loadSprite(...);` isn't `loadSprite()` a void function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ having trouble returning sf::Texture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546372/c-having-trouble-returning-sftexture)

Comment: Just have a look at [my previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19546977/520217), it's the same problem in the end.

Comment: Ah I get it, so the sprite needs to be pointing to an existing texture as long as it lives. If I knew this it wouldnt have happened haha, maybe read the docs a bit better? Thankyou! @Hiura

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the sprite lives the sprite needs an existing texture to be present. As soon as the method ends the `sf::Texture holdtexture`would be cleared from the memory and because of that it would display an white square.

I fixed it by adding an sf::Texture to the Entity class and assigning that texture to the sprite.

Comment: Glad it was resolved! Remember to accept the correct answer.