# Loading image from memory

Tags: c++, sfml

According to the [documentation](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.1/classsf_1_1Texture.php), one can load an `sf::Texture` three different ways: from file, from stream, from memory. I think I need the latter, but I'm not even sure about that. And if I do, I can't figure out how to use it.

I have a method, which, given an url to work with, needs to return an `sf::Sprite`. I'm successfully downloading the binary data, and storing it in a string (since `Http::Response::getBody()` returns that). I know for a fact, that this is the right data, because if I write and save it to a file, I can view the image. I don't want a file however, I just need the image displayed.

Here is the function:

```
sf::Sprite Downloader::GetPicture(const std::string &url)
{
    sf::Http http;
    std::string host = url.substr(0, url.find("net/")+4 );
    std::string uri = url.substr(url.find("net/")+4, url.size());
    http.setHost(host);
    request.setUri(uri);
    response = http.sendRequest(request);
    std::string data = response.getBody();

    //THIS IS WRONG
    sf::Texture texture;    
    texture.loadFromMemory((void*)data, sizeof(data));
    return sf::Sprite(texture);

    /* THIS WORKS, BUT I DON'T WANT TO SAVE, REOPEN, THEN DELETE AT THE END
    std::ofstream fileout("test.jpg", std::ios::binary);
    fileout << data;
    fileout.close();
    */
}
```

Here is `loadFromMemory`'s [signature](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.1/classsf_1_1Texture.php#a2c4adb19dd4cbee0a588eeb85e52a249) for the lazy (the `void*` confuses me, that's probably the problem).

Also, this might be a completely wrong way to do it; maybe extending `sf::InputStream`, and using `loadFromStream`?

The problem is, returned `sf::Sprite` has 0×0 dimension and 0 size, that's how I know it's wrong.

Comment: Try `texture.loadFromMemory(data.data(), data.size());`

Comment: @Casey I think that's the solution, because it says `Failed to load image from memory. Reason : JPEG format not supported (progressive)`...

Comment: But documentation says `The supported image formats are bmp, png, tga, jpg, gif, psd, hdr and pic. Some format options are not supported, like progressive jpeg. If this function fails, the image is left unchanged.`

If the file format I'm downloading is `.jpg`, but it's still a progressive JPEG, how can I tell those apart?

Comment: I guess if it fails to load, it's progressive? (Warning: I know nothing about SFML except what it says in the tag wiki.)

Comment: @Casey Well, you did answer my original question, this is more of a file format thing now, so thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code. One was spotted by Casey, that is you should use `texture.loadFromMemory(data.data(), data.length())`.

The problem with `texture.loadFromMemory((void*)data, sizeof(data));` is that you will load some garbage and not necessarily the picture data; you will load the other attributes of the string (like an integer for the length, and maybe a pointer for the data itself).

The other one is related to the [white square problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429155/sftexture-as-class-member-doesnt-work/19434823#19434823): you return a sprite but not the texture. After the function returns, the texture is destroyed and the sprite will display only a white rectangle instead.

You could do something like:

```
sf::Texture dlpicture(std::string host, std::string uri)
{
    sf::Http http(host);
    sf::Http::Request request(uri);
    auto response = http.sendRequest(request);
    auto data = response.getBody();

    sf::Texture text;
    text.loadFromMemory(data.data(), data.length());

    return text;
}
```

which you can try with `sf::Texture texture = dlpicture("www.sfml-dev.org", "download/goodies/sfml-logo-small.png");`.

SFML indeed support jpg format but not all its variants. Progressive jpg is not supported for example. You'll have to use another format.

Comment: Thank you, I applied Casey's fix, and everything worked, but the white squares were indeed present. I briefly thought it might be because a local texture is being destroyed. I refactored the program since, because I found unnecessary code elsewhere, and now it works... The downloads are not fast enough though, I guess my next question will be about sharing that texture accross threads...:D