# My sfml ImageManager class is only displaying a white square in c++

Tags: c++, sprite, sfml

I know this topic is abundant in forums, but I need help for this specific issue. I'm following [this tutorial](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/wiki/Tutorial:-Image-Manager) to make a basic sfml ImageManager class for a tic tac toe game. I'm having trouble understanding how to implement this class in my game engine though. I'm going to post a lot of code as there are multiple classes involved:
Board.h: my tic-tac-toe game board.

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include "Box.h"
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include "ImageManager.h"

class Board{
public:
Board();
~Board();

std::vector<Box> &GetBoxes();

sf::Sprite GetGameBoard();
private:
sf::Sprite gameBoard;

std::vector<Box> boxes;
};
```

And here's Board.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Board.h"
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"

Board::Board(){
ImageManager imgr;
imgr.AddResourceDirectory("images/");
gameBoard.setTexture(imgr.GetImage("images/t3board.png"));
}

Board::~Board(){

}

std::vector<Box> &Board::GetBoxes(){
return boxes;
}

sf::Sprite Board::GetGameBoard(){
return gameBoard;
}
```

Here's what is relevant from the ImageManager class from the tutorial:

```
const sf::Texture &ImageManager::GetImage(const std::string &filename){
    for(std::map<std::string, sf::Texture>::const_iterator it = textures_.begin(); it != textures_.end(); ++it){
        if(filename == it->first){
            std::cout << "DEBUG_MESSAGE: " << filename << " using existing image.\n";
            return it->second;
        }
    }

    //if image doesn't exist (no need for else since it will return if filename is found
    sf::Texture texture;
    if(texture.loadFromFile(filename)){
        //create both a string and matching image in the map
        textures_[filename] = texture;
        std::cout << "DEBUG_MESSAGE: " << filename << " loading image.\n";
        return textures_[filename];
    }

    // If the image has still not been found, search all registered directories
    //of course, it will be empty until I specify extra directories by adding them into the vector
    for(std::vector< std::string >::iterator it = resourceDirectories_.begin(); it != resourceDirectories_.end(); ++it){
        if(texture.loadFromFile((*it) + filename )){
            textures_[filename] = texture;
            std::cout << "DEBUG_MESSAGE: " << filename << " loading image 2.\n";
            return textures_[filename];
        }
    }

    //again, notice there's no elses because returns serve as breaks
    std::cout << "GAME_ERROR: Image was not found. It is filled with an empty image.\n";
    textures_[filename] = texture;
    return textures_[filename];
}
```

Finally, in my engine, I get `gameBoard` and draw it to my window:

```
void Engine::Render(){
    window.clear();
    window.draw(board.GetGameBoard());
    window.display();
}
```

My window just shows a complete white background, but it's still functional otherwise. Can anybody see what I've done wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19434823/520217

Comment: Thanks, I understand the problem, but I don't understand the fix. Where would I need to set the texture's image so it doesn't get lost?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `textures_` is a private member of the `ImageManager` class? In that case you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because `ImageManager::GetImage` returns a *reference* to data stored in a container that is destroyed (remember that `imgr` is a local variable in the constructor).

Comment: It is indeed: `private: std::map<std::string, sf::Texture> textures_;`. So should `const sf::Texture &GetImage(const std::string &filename);` just be `const sf::Texture GetImage(const std::string &filename);` instead? Edit: that alone doesn't fix the issue. What else would need to change?

Comment: @jburn7 I don't have much experience with SFML (especially their `Sprint` class) but it seems like a likely culprit. If so then yes, returning by value would solve the problem.

Comment: Ok, how well do you know your `std::map`'s? Could this be the issue: `sf::Texture texture; if(texture.loadFromFile(filename)){
//create both a string and matching image in the map
textures_[filename] = texture;
std::cout << "DEBUG_MESSAGE: " << filename << " loading image.\n";
return textures_[filename];}` (sorry for the mess) Because from what I can tell, this is actually returning a string as an `sf::Texture`. Could my compiler just not be telling me this?

Comment: @jburn7 That part of the code should work. Actually, you could try making your image manager a singleton class, or at least make the `texture_` variable `static`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have it. It's a pretty embarrasing solution, but declaring my `ImageManager imgr` in the constructor of `Board` was destroying my ImageManager instantly, so I just cut that instance and pasted it in the header file. And for some reason returning a reference instead of the actual texture value was necessary, that also stumped me.