# SFML image didn't load and no error

Tags: c++, box2d, sfml

I don't know why it didn't give me error and I do not know where I'm wrong. The image suppose to be on my circle. circ_ is my circle in my circle class. I do not know if my image is loaded or not. The cout<<"Cannot load image"; didn't come out. My image path is in the same folder as all my cpp and header files.

```
sf::Texture image;
image.loadFromFile("basketballballpic.png");
if (!image.loadFromFile("basketballballpic.png"))
{
    // error...
    std::cout<<"Cannot load image";
}
circ_.setTexture(&image);
```

Comment: @Hiura do you mind explaining why??

Comment: might have read a bit too fast.. Is `circ_` a sprite? If yes, it shouldn't compile. Otherwise my guess it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429155/sftexture-as-class-member-doesnt-work/19434823

Comment: I suspect that `image` is a local variable and you should use dynamic allocation instead. Also, when you log errors to `std::cout`, always add `<< std::endl`to ensure that the output is written.

Comment: @Hiura the circ_ is CircleShape.. I don't understand the link that you've given.me..  Sorry I'm a newbie..  @@

Comment: @molbdnilo oooo okayokay I'll add..

Comment: @Hiura OMIGOSH i read the link you gave me and the sprite documentation that you've stated in the answer there like 4 times and know what's wrong. i just need to declare it outside header file because of the white square thing thank you so much!! <3