# SFML chess game pieces not rendering when part of a class that groups them together

Tags: c++, sfml

```
    #include "Field.h"

    Field::Field(const std::string& l_title, int size) : m_windows(l_title, sf::Vector2u(size, size)),
    m_squareDim(size / 8), m_chessGrid(m_squareDim), m_wTeam(TeamColor::WHITE, m_chessGrid), 
    m_bTeam(TeamColor::BLACK, m_chessGrid), m_knight(PieceType::W_KNIGHT, sf::Vector2f(105,105))
    {
        reset();
    }

    void Field::reset()
    {   
        drawTeamStart();
    }


    void Field::render()
    {
        m_windows.BeginDraw();
        constructChessBoard();
        m_windows.Draw(m_knight.getPieceSprite());
        drawTeamStart();
        m_windows.EndDraw();
    }

    void Field::drawTeamStart() //draws both the black and white team in their starting positions
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            m_windows.Draw(m_wTeam.m_chessPieces[i].getPieceSprite());
            m_windows.Draw(m_bTeam.m_chessPieces[i].getPieceSprite());
        }
    }


struct Grid {

    sf::Vector2f m_gridMap[8][8];

    Grid(float squareDim) {
        sf::Vector2f coord;
        coord.x += squareDim/2;
        coord.y += squareDim/2;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            coord.y += squareDim;
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                coord.x += squareDim;
                m_gridMap[i][j] = coord;
            }
        }
    }

};


#pragma once

#include "SFML\Graphics.hpp"
#include "Grid.h"

enum PieceType { 
    W_BISHOP,
    W_PAWN,
    W_KING,
    W_QUEEN,
    W_ROOK,
    W_KNIGHT,
    B_BISHOP,
    B_PAWN,
    B_KING,
    B_QUEEN,
    B_ROOK,
    B_KNIGHT
};

class GamePieces 
{
public:
    GamePieces(){}
    GamePieces(const PieceType& type, const sf::Vector2f& position) : m_type(type),m_position(position)
    {
        switch (type) {
            case W_BISHOP:
                m_gamePiece.loadFromFile("w_bishop.png");
                break;
            //other cases are practically the same
        }
        m_size = m_gamePiece.getSize();
        m_gamePieceSprite.setTexture(m_gamePiece);
        m_gamePieceSprite.setOrigin(sf::Vector2f(m_size.x/2, m_size.y/2));
        m_gamePieceSprite.setPosition(position);
    }

    sf::Sprite getPieceSprite() const {
        return m_gamePieceSprite;
    }

private:
    sf::Texture m_gamePiece;
    sf::Sprite m_gamePieceSprite;
    sf::Vector2f m_position;
    PieceType m_type;
    sf::Vector2u m_size;
};


#pragma once
#include "SFML\Graphics.hpp"
#include "GamePieces.h"

enum TeamColor {
    BLACK,
    WHITE
};

struct Team {
    //16 pieces in regular chess
    //map that assigns specific game pieces coordinates

    GamePieces m_chessPieces[16];
    TeamColor color;

    Team(const TeamColor& color, const Grid& grid) { //reference to constant grid variable
        sf::Vector2f coord;

    switch (color) {
        case WHITE:
        {
            m_chessPieces[0] = GamePieces(PieceType::W_ROOK, grid.m_gridMap[0][0]);
            m_chessPieces[1] = GamePieces(PieceType::W_KNIGHT, grid.m_gridMap[0][1]);
            m_chessPieces[2] = GamePieces(PieceType::W_BISHOP, grid.m_gridMap[0][2]);
            m_chessPieces[3] = GamePieces(PieceType::W_KING, grid.m_gridMap[0][3]);
            m_chessPieces[4] = GamePieces(PieceType::W_QUEEN, grid.m_gridMap[0][4]);
            m_chessPieces[5] = GamePieces(PieceType::W_BISHOP, grid.m_gridMap[0][5]);
            m_chessPieces[6] = GamePieces(PieceType::W_KNIGHT, grid.m_gridMap[0][6]);
            m_chessPieces[7] = GamePieces(PieceType::W_ROOK, grid.m_gridMap[0][7]);
            int counter = 8;
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                //arranging pawns left to right on 
                m_chessPieces[counter] = GamePieces(PieceType::W_PAWN, grid.m_gridMap[1][j]);
                counter++;
            }
        }
        break;

        default:
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                //arranging pawns left to right on 
                m_chessPieces[j] = GamePieces(PieceType::B_PAWN, grid.m_gridMap[7][j]);
            }

            m_chessPieces[8] = GamePieces(PieceType::B_ROOK, grid.m_gridMap[8][0]);
            m_chessPieces[9] = GamePieces(PieceType::B_KNIGHT, grid.m_gridMap[8][1]);
            m_chessPieces[10] = GamePieces(PieceType::B_BISHOP, grid.m_gridMap[8][2]);
            m_chessPieces[11] = GamePieces(PieceType::B_KING, grid.m_gridMap[8][3]);
            m_chessPieces[12] = GamePieces(PieceType::B_QUEEN, grid.m_gridMap[8][4]);
            m_chessPieces[13] = GamePieces(PieceType::B_BISHOP, grid.m_gridMap[8][5]);
            m_chessPieces[14] = GamePieces(PieceType::B_KNIGHT, grid.m_gridMap[8][6]);
            m_chessPieces[15] = GamePieces(PieceType::B_ROOK, grid.m_gridMap[8][7]);
        }
        }
    }
};
```

So the problem is that its not rendering properly, sometimes a few white squares appear in place of the sprite. I've put a GamePiece object directly as a member of the Field class the m_knight as a test, and that renders fine so its nothing wrong with my objects.

Comment: You aren't checking if the sprites load correctly.

Comment: ok i can do that but they should be loading correctly regardless

Comment: its not working even with the checks, nothing wrong with loading them

Comment: Never assume. Always check. I'd help you with debugging, but you can do that yourself. If you want us to help, boil your code down to a minimal example.

Comment: Hi, not sure what im looking for in the debugger honestly. ive edited my question to cut out the unnecessary stuff, hopefully you give a look, its still a bit long but hopefully its ok

Comment: It's still a lot of code. Try to make it smaller. Try to make the smallest program possible that still has the same issue. If you insist on having lots of code, at least explain and document it.

Comment: This is almost assuredly the [white square problem](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/graphics-sprite.php#the-white-square-problem). Either the texture has been destroyed, or it wasn't loaded in the first place. You need to check if the load succeeded, too `sf::Texture::loadFromFile` *returns a bool for a reason*.

Comment: Ok its been fixed, by looking at white square problem. Apparently I had to make the array in "Team" dynamic so it wouldnt lose the texture...now its giving me a debut assertion failure, something to do with heap corruption

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sf::Texture as class member doesn't work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429155/sftexture-as-class-member-doesnt-work)