# SFML 2.3 can't render texture with RectangleShape child

Tags: c++, sfml

I seem to be experiencing a problem with adding a texture to my one class named Paddle that has a superclass of sf::RectangleShape.
I'm using the texture as a variable in the header to avoid it being trashed after the scope of the constructor like so:

```
class Paddle : public sf::RectangleShape {
private:
    // other variables here
    sf::Texture texture;
};
```

Then in my Paddle.cpp I'm using the following:

```
Paddle::Paddle(Game* game) 
    : RectangleShape(sf::Vector2f(WIDTH, HEIGHT)) {
    // some code here

    if (!texture.loadFromFile("paddle-texture.png")) {
        std::cout << "Couldn't load paddle texture" << std::endl;
    }

    setTexture(&texture);
    setPosition((windowSize.x / 2 - WIDTH / 2), (windowSize.y - 20));
}
```

However, this doesn't work for whatever reason. I've tried moving the texture outside of the Paddle class altogether and it still doesn't have a problem. Also, I think I should mention that the "couldn't load paddle texture" message does not appear to the console.

The other thing I did is writing in my main.cpp:

```
sf::RectangleShape paddle(sf::Vector2f(100, 10));
sf::Texture texture;
if (!texture.loadFromFile("paddle-texture.png")) {
    std::cout << "Couldn't load paddle texture" << std::endl;
}
paddle.setTexture(&texture);
```

Which works perfectly and renders with its texture! However, I lose the functionality and cleanliness of my class if I use this. So I'm wondering why it's rendering the texture in the Main.cpp but not as a class object that inherits the RectangleShape class?

**Edit:**
Due to a request, I'll explain my expected and actual results. Right now I'm trying to render a paddle with a texture (paddle-texture.png); however, I'm getting a white paddle (or whatever the fill colour is set to) as if it's not using the texture at all.

To call the create the Paddle I use the following:

```
Paddle paddle;
```

Then with the Window I use:

```
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600, 600), "My Project with SFML");

// some code here
// could use the following here:
// Paddle paddle;

window.setFramerateLimit(64);

while (window.isOpen()) {
    sf::Event event;

    // check if close button or esc key is pressed
    while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
        switch (event.type) {
        case sf::Event::Closed:
            window.close();
            break;
        case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
            if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
                window.close();
            break;
        }
    }

    // render everything onto the screen
    window.clear();
    window.draw(frameDisplay);
    game.drawObjects(); // this is a custom object but could be replaced with:
    // window.draw(paddle);
    window.display();
}
```

Comment: (ignore prev comment, deleted) How are `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` defined? if you manually put in `RectangleShape(sf::Vector2f(100, 10))` and accordingly with the dimension variables, does it work?

Comment: @XerenNarcy are defined by `#define WIDTH 100` and `#define HEIGHT 10`

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: Ho, and my gut feeling tells me this is a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19429155/520217

Comment: @Hiura Hmm... I'm not certain I understand you, do you mean that it's bad practice or that what I put doesn't work?

Comment: @Hiura I just went over the link you provided but I don't believe this is a dup of the same problem as I'm not using a duplicate of the instance, there's only one paddle in the game as of right now; thus I don't believe the `Copy constructor` to be the problem. Or perhaps I simply just don't understand, could you elaborate a bit more on this?

Comment: Explain what doesn't work. What are you seeing? What do you expect instead? And provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've made an edit to re-summarise the actual and expected results to clear up any ambigutity. As far as I know I have provided a "mcve" as it meets those things. Unless you're talking about the image that's not being provided but I'm sure you could use any texture-like image to accomplish this. If there's something more specific that I'm leaving out please tell me, cheers!

Comment: The 'c' of *mcve* means *complete*. Put in other words, give a piece of code that we can compile, not just a snippet of some small part of your program. You can see another definition of this *mcve* thing here: http://sscce.org/

Comment: @Hiura Thanks for your help! I've made another edit so that you can have enough code for it to compile with SFML!